# Loop over Django objects and Bootstrap cards

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to use `Bootstrap cards` in order to create one card by object and add some sub_objects in each one.

For example :

I have an object `Publication` which could contain one or many sub_objects `Document`.

**Publication object** has some attributes : `category`, `title`, `picture`, `description` and **Document object** has some attributes like `title`, `format`, `language`, ...

I would like to get something like this :

[image]

For a same category, I create a card by publication and I list all documents for each publication.

This is what I get with my code :

[image]

As you can see, I should have **document n°1** and **document°2** in the same card and not two different cards.

This is my code :

```
{% for category in research_categories|dictsort:'name' %}
  <div class="row">
    <fieldset>
      <legend id="category_{{ category.id }}"><span class="name">{{ category }}</span></legend>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        {% for element in test_research %}
          {% if element.publication.category|stringformat:"s"  == category|stringformat:"s" %}
            {% ifchanged %}
              <div class="card" style="width:250px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ element.publication.cover.url }}" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">{{ element.publication }}</h4>

                  <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td> {{ element.title }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endifchanged %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And my view according to this part is :

```
# By default, display documents
test_research = Document.objects.all().order_by('publication__title', 'title', 'language', 'format')

research_categories = defaultdict(list)
for element in test_research:
    research_categories[element.publication.category].append(element)

research_publications = defaultdict(list)
for element in test_research:
    research_publications[element.publication].append(element)

kwargs['test_research'] = test_research
kwargs['research_categories'] = research_categories
kwargs['research_publications'] = research_publications
```

Comment: did you found a way to do this